# wcf service is giving reference error when I am adding reference to external dll in bin folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, dll

I have a wcf service in asp.net (C#) which I declared in the code like this.

```
 DMSOPInvoice.DMSServiceClient objdms = new DMSOPInvoice.DMSServiceClient();
```

When I am adding a reference to a dll , the declarartion above is not working.
It is saying "**The type or namespace name 'DMSOPInvoice' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"**

The error message showing in the error window is given below.

**Error 38  Reference.svcmap: Failed to generate code for the service reference 'DMSOPInvoice'.
  Cannot import wsdl:portType 
 Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
  Error: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute'
 from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
  XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IDMSService'] 
 Cannot import wsdl:binding  Detail:
 There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
  XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IDMSService'] 
 XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IDMSService'] 
 Cannot import wsdl:port  Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.  XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:binding[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IDMSService']  XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://tempuri.org/']/wsdl:service[@name='DMSService']/wsdl:port[@name='BasicHttpBinding_IDMSService'] App_WebReferences/DMSOPInvoice/**

Can anyone help me on this please..?

Comment: You mean that having not added the reference to this specific dll, there is no error? What is this dll? Is this the dll of the service reference?

Comment: Yes, if I removed the dll there is no error.
The dll is not of the service reference.It is used for other purpose.

Comment: The only reason i can imagine is some type of conflict in the DMSOPInvoice namespace, maybe it is in the specific dll you are talking about. No offense, but I think, with this kind of information there could not be any solution found. :)